# Convert Proc rank to SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

I am working on a project where a model that was built in SAS has to implemented into Oracle SQL.
My question is simply how can I do this in Oracle SQL:

```
data have;
infile datalines delimiter=',';
input var $ value;
datalines;                      
var_x,1
var_x,1
var_x,1
var_x,2
var_x,2
var_x,2
var_x,3
var_x,3
var_x,3
var_x,4
var_x,4
var_x,5
;
run;

proc rank data=have out=want groups=10 ties=high;
var value;
ranks rank;
run;
```

Have:
[image]

Want: [image]

Comment: Edit your question and explain exactly the result set you want produced.

Comment: please explain why rank for value 5 is 9.

Comment: SAS ranks the value starting from 0. Since the proc rank procedure split the dataset into 10 ranks, the maximum rank is 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This SAS blog post](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2019/07/19/how-the-rank-procedure-calculates-ranks-with-groups-and-ties/) goes into detail about what the `proc rank` function does.

Specifically:

> The formula for calculating group values is as follows:
>
> FLOOR(rank*k/(n+1))
>
> In this formula:
>
> - rank is the data value's rank order
> - k is the value of the GROUPS= option
> - n is the number of nonmissing values

k = 10, and n = `count(*) over ()`, so those are easy.

We can also replicate SAS' `rank` behavior in Oracle, but it requires 2 levels of analytical functions, so we need an inline view.

```
create table have (var varchar2(10), value number);

insert into have values ('var_x',1);
insert into have values ('var_x',1);
insert into have values ('var_x',1);
insert into have values ('var_x',2);
insert into have values ('var_x',2);
insert into have values ('var_x',2);
insert into have values ('var_x',3);
insert into have values ('var_x',3);
insert into have values ('var_x',3);
insert into have values ('var_x',4);
insert into have values ('var_x',4);
insert into have values ('var_x',5);

select var, value, 
    FLOOR( max(r) over (partition by value)*10 / c ) as proc_rank_high
from ( 
  select var, value,
    rank() over (order by value, rowid) r,
    count(1) over ()+1 c
  from have
);
```

With the "ties=high" option, SAS calculates the rank as the max rank for that unique value, which is what I'm doing with `max(r)` here.

(It might be more intuitive to use `row_number() over (order by value)` for `r` instead of `rank() over (order by value, rowid)` - your call. They do the same thing.)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL pass through to Oracle use Oracle `RANK` function.  You might also need to use `CEIL` or `FLOOR`
to bound the result to the range 1 .. 10

Comment: More likely something based on PERCENT_RANK() instead.  Oracle RANK() is just counting, not dividing into bins like the example PROC RANK statement does.